# What real-life people have been outed as aliens in Men in Black?

Tags: men-in-black

In the *Men in Black* film series, many celebrities are revealed to be secret aliens. I would just like to know which celebrities have been outed, either on a video screen, through a name-drop, or otherwise.

Comment: The only ones I remember are Michael Jackson and Dennis Rodman.

Comment: Elvis. He didn't die. He just returned home AFAIR.

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119654/trivia

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Men in Black

On the MIB surveillance screen we see **Al Roker, Isaac Mizrahi, Danny DeVito,** (director) **Barry Sonnenfeld, Chloe Sonnenfeld** (Director's daughter), **Sylvester Stallone, Dionne Warwick, Newt Gingrich, Anthony Robbins, George Lucas,** and (executive producer) **Steven Spielberg.**

[image]

Additionally, there's mention that **Elvis Presley** is an alien (and still very much alive).

> **Kay:** No, Elvis is not dead. He just went home

As well as **Dennis Rodman.**

> **Jay:** *Alright, let's put in a call to Dennis Rodman. He's from that planet.*

---

### Men in Black II

**Michael Jackson** (although interestingly the director says that he [isn't an alien](http://collider.com/barry-sonnenfeld-men-in-black-3-interview-2/) which would seem to conflict with the dialogue in the film)

> **Z:** *I'm still working on the alien "affirmative action" programme*

[image]

**Martha Stewart** (seen in the viewscreen, but not definitively identified as an alien)

[image]

---

### Men In Black 3

On the surveillance screen we see a number of celebrities; **Brainoid (Bill Gates), Lady Gaga, Richard Branson, Justin Beiber, David Beckham and Yao Ming.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't Andy Warhol outed as a MIB agent in 3, too?  Perhaps some famous models of that era as aliens, as well.

Comment: @eshier - Andy Warhol is outed as "Agent K", a (human) MIB agent.

Comment: @Yes, that's true about Warhol (Agent W).  Meant it as a side-note, not a request to add to the answer.  Though looking into it, some places list Yao Ming as an alien shown (and it looks like him next to Branson in the picture above).  He may be a regional addition, though.

Comment: Now, I see how MIB gets that much money. When Bill Gates is an alien, MIB deserves hefty tax.